# Change plot line thickness in ScottPlot

Tags: c#, scottplot

How can I change the plot line thickness in ScottPlot? And preferably also point thickness.

I've tried:

```
var plt = new Plot(1000, 500);
plt.AddScatter(times, temperatures, Color.Blue);
plt.LineWidth = 4;
```

But `LineWidth` apparently only works for signal plots (where `AddSignal()` is used instead of `AddScatter()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through the constructor:

```cs
plt.AddScatter(times, temperatures, Color.Blue, lineWidth: lineWidth, markerSize: markerSize)
```

Based on this example here: https://scottplot.net/cookbook/4.1/category/plottable-scatter-plot/#custom-lines

For what it's worth, setting `LineWidth` does work, but it looks like you tried to set the linewidth of the plotting window rather than the actual scatter plot. This should work better:

```cs
var plt = new Plot(1000, 500);
var scat = plt.AddScatter(times, temperatures, Color.Blue);
scat.LineWidth = 4;
scat.MarkerSize = markerSize;
```

If you need more, you might want to check out the ScatterPlot docs. The docs haven't been available for very long unfortunately, but now that they're here they're a great source: https://scottplot.net/doc/v4/api/ScottPlot.Plottable.ScatterPlot.html